# How to get listener object when binding to a specific address in Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express 4.16.2

If I only pass a port number to express

```
listener = app.listen(3000);
console.log(listener.address().port);
```

I get `3000` in the console.

If I bind to a specific address

```
listener = app.listen(3000, '192.168.0.10');
console.log(listener.address().port);
```

I get the following error

```
console.log(listener.address().port);
                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'port' of null
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\development\node\redbird_redis\app.js:13:31)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must wait for the [`listening`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_address) event to emit:

> Don't call `server.address()` until the `'listening'` event has been emitted.

The simplest and most canonical way to do that is to add a callback to the `.listen()` invocation:

```
server = app.listen(3000, '192.168.0.10', () => console.log(server.address().port));
```